# Can I run two isolated Google Chrome windows using a single Selenium driver?

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests

I would like to test interactions between two logged in users on a website that only allows a single user to be logged in for a given browser session. The reason I'd like to avoid creating a second driver is because I'd prefer to use Selenium's provided Docker containers to run my tests (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium), which seem to operate on a "one port-one driver" basis, with only a single exposed port. Selenium Grid is not an option due to the pipeline environment these tests will be running in.

The two windows do not need to be able to run actions concurrently, but since my test case is two logged-in users interacting with each other, neither user can log out while the other user is performing actions.

Using two drivers in my own Docker container is my last resort, as I've found it to be less fast and reliable than Selenium's own containers, but I'll go that route if I have no other option.

Comment: You can use Threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that what I was trying to do was not possible. However, for my use case, I was able to spin up an additional Selenium provided Docker image that would be listening on a different port, allowing me to set up two drivers.